# Determining if a variable is within range?

Tags: ruby, integer, conditional-statements, range

I need to write a loop that does something like:

```
if i (1..10)
  do thing 1
elsif i (11..20)
  do thing 2
elsif i (21..30)
  do thing 3
etc...
```

But so far have gone down the wrong paths in terms of syntax.

Answer (score 321):

```
if i.between?(1, 10)
  do thing 1 
elsif i.between?(11,20)
  do thing 2 
...
```

Comment: This also works for `Date` and `DateTime` objects while `===` does not.

Comment: `i.between?(1..10)` won't work (if it is `..`)  I suppose there must be a reason for it

Comment: **between?** would need two parameters it would not allow range.

Comment: is it inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: @andrewcockerham Inclusive. `3.between?(1, 3) => true`

Answer (score 93):

Use the `===` operator (or its synonym `include?`)

```
if (1..10) === i
```

Comment: Has the nice benefit of also working with `i` being something else than a number (like `nil`)

Comment: Wouldn't seem like a very efficient solution if the range had been significantly large.

Comment: For future reader, the alternative way `if i === (1..10)` won't work

Comment: @rthbound, why? `(1..10000000000000000)`  isn't an array. `(1..10000000000000000) === 5000000000000000` is just doing a "between" test under the hood

Comment: @Anwar could you explain why it doesn't work the other way?

Comment: @GovindRai for a single `i`, the `===` works as equivalent operator, of course `i` is not equal to `(1..10)` range. However, for range, `===` works as  `include?` method.

Answer (score 72):

As @Baldu said, use the === operator or use case/when which internally uses === :

```
case i
when 1..10
  # do thing 1
when 11..20
  # do thing 2
when 21..30
  # do thing 3
etc...
```

Comment: of all the answers, this is also likely the most performant when you have multiple ranges.

Answer (score 42):

if you still wanted to use ranges...

```
def foo(x)
 if (1..10).include?(x)
   puts "1 to 10"
 elsif (11..20).include?(x)
   puts "11 to 20"
 end
end
```

Answer (score 12):

You could use
`if (1..10).cover? i then thing_1
elsif (11..20).cover? i then thing_2`

and according to this benchmark in [Fast Ruby](https://github.com/JuanitoFatas/fast-ruby#cover-vs-include-code) is faster than `include?`

Comment: This is actually a lot faster

Answer (score 10):

You can usually get a lot better performance with something like:

```
if i >= 21
  # do thing 3
elsif i >= 11
  # do thing 2
elsif i >= 1
  # do thing 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Not a direct answer to the question, but if you want the opposite to "within":

```
(2..5).exclude?(7)
```

> true

Comment: Note that `exclude?` is a [Rails addition](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/exclude%3F).

Answer (score 6):

If you need the fastest way to do it, use the good old comparing.

```
require 'benchmark'

i = 5
puts Benchmark.measure { 10000000.times {(1..10).include?(i)} }
puts Benchmark.measure { 10000000.times {i.between?(1, 10)}   }
puts Benchmark.measure { 10000000.times {1 <= i && i <= 10}   }
```

on my system prints:

```
0.959171   0.000728   0.959899 (  0.960447)
0.919812   0.001003   0.920815 (  0.921089)
0.340307   0.000000   0.340307 (  0.340358)
```

As you can see, double comparing is **almost 3 times faster** than `#include?` or `#between?` methods!

Answer (score 1):

A more dynamic answer, which can be built in Ruby:

```
def select_f_from(collection, point) 
  collection.each do |cutoff, f|
    if point <= cutoff
      return f
    end
  end
  return nil
end

def foo(x)
  collection = [ [ 0, nil ],
                 [ 10, lambda { puts "doing thing 1"} ],
                 [ 20, lambda { puts "doing thing 2"} ],
                 [ 30, lambda { puts "doing thing 3"} ],
                 [ 40, nil ] ]

  f = select_f_from(collection, x)
  f.call if f
end
```

So, in this case, the "ranges" are really just fenced in with nils in order to catch the boundary conditions.

Answer (score -2):

For Strings:

```
(["GRACE", "WEEKLY", "DAILY5"]).include?("GRACE")
```

#=>true