# Check if an integer is within a range

Tags: ruby

Is there a simple way to evaluate whether an integer is within that range using the `(2..100)` syntax.

For example, say I wanted to evaluate as true if my integer `x = 100`, and my range is `(0..200)`, I'm just looking for the simple, concise ruby-way of doing this.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

There are many ways of doing the same things in Ruby. You can check if value is in the range by use of following methods,

`14.between?(10,20) # true`

`(10..20).member?(14) # true`

`(10..20).include?(14) # true`

But, I would suggest using `between?` rather than `member?` or `include?`

All number literals denote inclusive ranges.
You can find more about it on [Ruby in Rails](http://rubyinrails.com/2013/09/03/how-to-check-if-value-is-included-in-between-the-range/).

Comment: Also covered in the [Ruby community style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/commit/1b8c788c836f00507056eba21d4b9ca8078eec3e).

Answer (score 22):

You can use the [=== operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467538/what-does-the-operator-do-in-ruby#4467823):

```
(1..10) === 1 #=> true
(1..10) === 100 #=> false
```

Comment: Just note, when using this solution I found that You need to be aware of order in which is condition written `1 === (1..10)` will produce false

Answer (score 12):

you can use the `member?` method of the range to test this

```
 (1..10).member?(1)   => true
 (1..10).member?(100) => false
```

Answer (score 9):

```
(2..100).include?(5) #=> true
(2..100).include?(200) #=> false
```

Note that `2..0` is an empty range, so `(2..0).include?(x)` will return `false` for all values of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this question: [Determining if a variable is within range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870507/determining-if-a-variable-is-within-range-ruby)