# Difference between == and case?

Tags: ruby, parsing, file

I'm new to Ruby and am trying to work something out which is confusing me.  While writing a simple parser, I found that comparing a char with a `==` would produce a different result than comparing it with a `case` expression:

```
File.open('Quote.txt') do |f|
  f.chars.each do |c|
    puts c == '"' ? 'Quote' : 'Err'

    puts case c
    when '"' then 'QuoteCase'
    else          'ErrCase'
    end

    p c == '"', c === '"', c
  end
end
```

Assuming `Quote.txt` is a 1-byte file containing a single quote character (`0x22`), this produces:

```
Quote
ErrCase
true
true
"\""
```

I'm assuming I've done something wrong, but I can't figure out what it is.  Can anyone help?

This is in Ruby 1.9.2, by the way.

Comment: What is the type of c? And what is the type of "\""? Does `c === "\""` work?

Comment: String, String and yes, in that order.

Comment: I took the liberty of making the code a bit more Rubyish (all those backslashes made my eyes bleed :-) ) and add some debugging.

Comment: I'm stumped. Normally, while I can't necessarily see *what* is wrong, I can at least see *where* something *might* be wrong, but in this case I'm coming up empty.

Comment: @Jörg Have you tried running the code though? I'm not getting the same output - it works as expected on my machine.

Comment: @Skilldrick: Yes, I did. I get exactly the output I edited into the question, which is also what the OP got. (In fact, I cut&pasted it.)

Comment: @Jörg weird. How are you creating your test file?

Comment: @Skilldrick: A friend of mine tried this out on an old 1.8.6 install that he has, and it works on that.  Which version are you running?  PS. Sorry for my noob backslash-heavy Ruby syntax. :-(

Comment: @Skilldrick: I'm using p180 under Windows, downloaded from rubyinstaller.org.

Comment: I get the same output as @Fuz (also on Ruby 1.9.2 on Windows). I noticed c.is_ascii? is false for the case that is going wrong (loaded from single byte file), and c.force_encoding('ASCII') fixes it. Just to reiterate, === behaves as expected but 'case/when' doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug in YARV on windows. I get the correct output in JRuby 1.6.0:

```
# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]

# ruby test.rb
Quote
ErrCase
true
true
"\""

# jruby --1.9 -v
jruby 1.6.0 (ruby 1.9.2 patchlevel 136) (2011-03-15 f3b6154) (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.7.0-ea) [Windows XP-x86-java]

# jruby --1.9 test.rb
Quote
QuoteCase
true
true
"\""
```

Comment: Ah, I'm using MRI p136 - maybe there was a regression.

Comment: ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [i686-linux] gives the correct output

Comment: Can someone file a bug report?

Answer (score 3):

`case` uses the [triple-equal `===` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467538/what-does-the-operator-do-in-ruby#4467823) to check each case.

That said, I don't know why your example isn't working:

```
> c = "\""
> c == "\""
=> true
> c === "\""
=> true
```

Try removing the `.each` and explicitly setting `c` to the quote character and see what happens.

Generally, `===` is more forgiving than `==` in Ruby, so I can't imagine a case where `==` would match and `===` wouldn't.

**Edit:** I've just copied your code, with the same input (a file with a single `"` character) and got the following output:

```
Quote
QuoteCase
Err
ErrCase
```

(the last two are from the newline at the end of the file that Vim insists on).

Comment: If I add a `c = "\"" if c === "\""` line to the top of the block, it works as expected.  Also, if I do the same operation with each_char on a string containing a single quote character, rather than reading from a file, it works as expected.  Looks like a (fairly fundamental) bug.

Comment: I've just tried this out and had no problems - I'm not sure why you're getting this error.