# /ell/ === 'Hello' true in Ruby. Why?

Tags: ruby

This code:

```
/ell/ === 'Hello'
```

evalutes to 'true' in IRB.

I don't understand why this makes sense logically. Integer === 30 makes sense because 30 is a PART OF the Integer class, but in what way is the string 'Hello' a PART OF /ell/? I don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

Semantically you're saying does the regular expression 'ell' match the string 'Hello'. Since 'Hello' contains the substring 'ell', it is true.

The '===' method is described here:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `===` for anything in ruby except case equality, find the documentation on [Regex#===](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)

`Following a regular expression literal with the === operator allows you to compare against a String.`

/^[a-z]*$/ === "HELLO" #=> false
/^[A-Z]*$/ === "HELLO" #=> true

Answer (score 1):

The `===` the case operator, it is primarily used in case statements and should not really be seen by its own.

```
case my_string
   when /ll/ then puts 'the string migth be hello'
   when /x/ then  puts 'all i know is that the sting contain x'
   else puts 'I have no idea'
end
```

It can also be used in some other functions such as grep:

```
array = ['ll', 'aa', 'hello']  
p array.grep(/ll/){|x| x.upcase} #=> ["LL", "HELLO"]
```

Any other use is discouraged and it really does not need to make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression describes a language, i.e. a set of strings. The `===` checks whether the string is a member of that set.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4467823/2988) to a similar question for details.