# Rewrite method using case in Ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement, case

So I have defined this `class File` inside a `module` and what I want to do is rewrite the `self.parse` method so that it uses `case`. I'm new to `Ruby` so this is not straightforward for me. Also the method must contain in it's body no more than `8` lines of code. Any ideas how to do it? Also I asked it on `Code Review` and they said it was off topic for them.

---

```
module RBFS
    class File
        attr_accessor :content
        def initialize (data = nil)
            @content = data
        end

        def data_type
            case @content
                when NilClass then :nil
                when String then :string
                when TrueClass , FalseClass then :boolean
                when Float , Integer then :number 
                when Symbol then :symbol                                                              
            end
        end

       def serialize
           case @content
               when NilClass then "nil:"
               when String then "string:#{@content}"
               when TrueClass , FalseClass then "boolean:#{@content}"
               when Symbol then "symbol:#{@content}"
               when Integer , Float then "number:#{@content}"        
           end
       end

       def self.parse (str)
           arr = str.partition(':')
           if arr[0] == "nil" then return File.new(nil) end
           if arr[0] == "string" then return File.new(arr[2].to_s) end
           if (arr[0] == "boolean" && arr[2].to_s == 'true') then return File.new(true) end
           if (arr[0] == "boolean" && arr[2].to_s == 'false') then return File.new(false) end
           if arr[0] == "symbol" then return File.new(arr[2].to_sym) end
           return File.new(arr[2].to_i) if (arr[0] == "number" && arr[2].to_s.include?('.') == false)
           return File.new(arr[2].to_f) if (arr[0] == "number" && arr[2].to_s.include?('.') == true)
       end
   end
end
```

---

Example how 'RBFS::File.parse' works:

```
RBFS::File.parse("string:"Hello world") => #<RBFS::File:0x1c45098 @content="Hello world"> #Tested in irb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally prefer this:

```
def self.parse(arg)
  key, value = arg.to_s.split(':')
  {
    'nil'     => new(nil), 
    'string'  => new(value),
    'boolean' => new(value == 'true'),
    'symbol'  => new(value.to_sym),
    'number'  => new(value.include?('.') ? BigDecimal(value) : Integer(value))
  }[key]
end
```

Code above is actually of 2 lines, broken into multiple lines for readability sake. However, if using `case` is a must then you can change your code to this:

```
def self.parse(arg)
  key, value = arg.to_s.split(':')
  case key
  when 'nil' then new(nil)
  when 'string' then new(value)
  when 'boolean' then new(value == 'true')
  when 'symbol' then new(value.to_sym)
  when 'number' then new(value.include?('.') ? BigDecimal(value) : Integer(value))
  end
end
```

Comment: What is your view on changing the last `case` to `new(case key; when 'nil' then nil; when 'string then value...end)` or `arg = case key; when 'nil' then nil;....end; new(arg)`.?

Comment: I thought of doing that too, but, it wasn't looking good so I didn't write it, do you think it'd be a good idea to mention that as well? :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Two reasons - 1) `BigDecimal` is much reliable than `Float` in monetary calculations. 2) `BigDecimal` can be easily changed to float(`to_f`) but not the other way around.

Comment: Sorry, Surya, `BigNum` on the brain. Deleted my earlier comment and will delete this one too...

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, `case` statements test using the [case equality method `#===`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467538/what-does-the-operator-do-in-ruby). `#===` returns true for several different of comparisons beyond the type checking you've already implemented in `#serialize` and `#data_type`. For example:

```
Integer === 1    //=> true
Numeric === 1    //=> true
(1..10) === 1    //=> true
1 === 1          //=> true
```

With that knowledge, we can construct a `#parse` method as follows:

```
def parse(serialized)
  type, content = serialized.split(':') # A neat trick that'll make things more readable.
  case type
  when 'nil'
     # ...
  when 'string'
     # ...
  when 'boolean'
     # ...
  when 'symbol'
     # ...
  when 'number'
     # ...
  else
    raise "Invalid RBFS file."
  end
end
```

I'm not sure that you'll be able to do this in 8 lines without compromising the file's readability or dropping the error handling step I added at the end (which I highly recommend), but to get close, you can use the `when ... then ...` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a suggestion for one way you might write this.  It is untested, of course.  I made two assumptions:

- what you refer to as `a[2]` is a string, so `a[2].to_s` is unnecessary.
- if `a[0] => "boolean"`, `a[2]` is `'true'` or `'false'`.

```
module RBFS
  class File
    attr_accessor :content
    def initialize (data = nil)
      @content = data
    end

    def data_type
      class_to_sym[@content.class]
    end

    def serialize
      return nil if @content.class == NilClass
      "#{class_to_sym[@content.class].to_s}:#{@content}"
    end

    def self.parse (str)
      type,_,val = str.partition(':')
      File.new(type_to_arg(type, val))
    end

    private

    def class_to_sym
       { NilClass=>:nil, String=>:string, TrueClass=>:boolean,
         FalseClass=>:boolean, Numeric=>:number, Symbol=>:symbol }
    end

    def type_to_arg(type, val)
      case type
        when "nil"     then nil
        when "string"  then val
        when "boolean" then val == 'true' 
        when "symbol"  then val.to_sym 
        when "numeric" then val[/\./] ? val.to_f : val.to_i 
        end
      end
    end

  end
end
```

If you prefer, you could replace `val[/\./]` with `val.include?('.')`.

You could alternatively use a hash to simulate a case statement in `type_to_arg`:

```
def type_to_arg(type, val)
  { "nil"    =>nil,
    "string" =>val,
    "boolean"=>(val=='true'),
    "symbol" =>val.to_sym,
    "number" =>val[/\./] ? val.to_f : val.to_i
  }[type]
end
```

Comment: What exactly you meant by: *Note that `99.class => Fixnum`, not `Integer`*?

Comment: It seems I messed up again, but thanks. I replaced `Fixnum=>:number, Float=>:number` in my hash `Class_to_Sym` with just `Float=>:number`. That should work OK. Correct? Let me know of any other problems you spot.

Comment: Looks good to me. Just one thing, maybe it's more of a coding style preference, so I'd say neglect it if you don't like the idea. I guess `Class_to_Sym` can be private method instead of a constant, reason is a constant will be initialized and occupies memory, while method will be initializing that hash till its scope. Also, a constant can be altered in code, while a method can not be altered. I remember in one answer you'd moved a calculative code to a method, so I thought why not move `case type ..` to a class method and then call: `File.new(determine_type type )`?

Comment: @Suyra. thanks for the advice. I've implemented both suggestions.