# Why does self.class === MyClass return false, while self.class == MyClass returns true?

Tags: ruby

I'm using Ruby's `case` syntax to set up some simple logic based on `self.class` as follows:

```
case self.class
 when FirstClass
   do stuff....
 when SecondClass
   do other stuff...
 end
```

I soon realized this always returns `nil.` Upon closer investigation, I found that `case` uses `===` rather than `==` to check equality. When running `self.class == FirstClass` in my terminal I get `true` as expected, however `self.class === FirstClass` returns `false`.

Looking into the ruby docs, I found the [following explanation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) of `===`:

> Case Equality – For class Object, effectively the same as calling #==,
>   but typically overridden by descendants to provide meaningful
>   semantics in case statements.

Can anyone out there shed some light on what may be happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This wasn't enlightening to me, but Class descends from Module, whose === impl is here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#3D-3D-3D-method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467538/what-does-the-operator-do-in-ruby

Comment: http://truffles.me.uk/rubys-equality-operator

Comment: It may help to know that the `#` in front of `==` just indicates that `==` is an instance method (much in the way that you often see things like `SomeClass#an_instance_method`). If literally wrote `#==` you would just end up commenting out the rest of the line.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - using that info, I found that `MyClass === my_instance` returns `true`, while `my_instance === MyClass` still returns `false`. Since I'm trying to set `case` based on `self.class`, I can't use the first case and the second still doesn't work.

Comment: You wouldn't expect `a-b` to equal `b-a` or `a/b` to equal `b/a`, so why should you expect `a===b` to equal `b===a`? The reason, I expect, is simply because  the method names `===` and `==` have a similar appearance and `a==b` if `b==a`, and because `===` is sometimes (unfortunately, perhaps) referred to as "case equality".  If `===` were instead named `method7` and executed `a.method7(b)` would you expect it to return the same value as `b.method7(a)`? Probably not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clue is in “typically overridden by descendants to provide meaningful semantics in case statements”, in particular [`Module` overrides it](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D):

> Case Equality — Returns `true` if *obj* is an instance of *mod* or one of *mod*’s descendants. Of limited use for modules, but can be used in `case` statements to classify objects by class.

So for modules `===` acts very much like the `is_a?` method (in fact it just calls the same implementing function in MRI Ruby, `rb_obj_is_kind_of`). In your example it evaluates to `false` because `self.class` isn’t an instance of `FirstClass`. It’s likely to just be an instance of `Class`. `self` alone however could be an instance:

```
case self
when FirstClass
  do stuff....
when SecondClass
  do other stuff...
end
```

(Although I think your design might not be quite right, testing the class of an object is usually a code smell. Instead you probably should have different implementations of a method in the objects.)

Comment: Nice, works like a charm (great explanation as well). Re. the code smell: I definitely agree, it's kind of a funky use case - the `case` checks Class and then calls the appropriate variation of a method. Normally I'd just throw methods in their respective classes, but in this case I'm trying to get all the logic related to a specific feature in a single place.

Comment: Good answer. Another example is [Regexp#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D). For example, `/a/==='cat' #=> true`, but it's really only used in `case` statements: `case 'cat'; when /a/...`.