# Dynamically mapping of value range and output

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a method to calculate the shipping cost for a package. The shipping cost comes in a table which states the weight range and the corresponding price.

Example data:

```
0 - 50g : $1
51 - 100g : $2
```

How should I structure my data, how can I generate the price dynamically based on the data instead of writing many `if` statements?

Example code:

```
def price_for_weight(w)    
  if w < 50
    return 1
  elsif w < 100
    return 2
  end
```

Comment: about 30 categories, There is no direct relationship between weight and price e.g. should be able to specify price for each category.

Comment: side note: in Ruby you don't need to specify `return` unless you have an expression that would terminate the execution of the method prematurely. Ruby methods automatically return the return value of the last evaluated expression.

Comment: @sixty4bit thanks, I just like to see the word return, gives me assurance haha.

Comment: what is the price  if weight is 50.5g?

Comment: @WandMaker good catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do this is to structure your data as a `Hash` with `Range` objects as the keys like so:

```
SHIPPING_COSTS = {
  0..50 => 1,
  51..100 => 2,
}
```

Using `Enumerable#select` in your method, you can then get a key-value pair using the `===` operator:

```
 def price_for_weight(w)    
    SHIPPING_COSTS.select { |range| range === w }
 end
```

`===` used with a set asks whether the value on the right side of the comparison can be considered a member of the set on the left side (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467538/what-does-the-operator-do-in-ruby)).

Since the above would return a key-value pair, you could add `.values.first` after the block to get just the cost:

```
 def price_for_weight(w)    
    SHIPPING_COSTS.select { |range| range === w }.values.first
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the costs are not always whole dollars, counting in cents is better.

```
ShippingCost = {50 => 100, 100 => 200}

def price_for_weight(w)
  ShippingCost[ShippingCost.keys.bsearch{|k| w <= k}]
end
```

Comment: As precaution, should keys be sorted using `ShippingCost.keys.sort.bsearch{...}` ?

Comment: the cost is just a mapping from the range, so I could still use 1.01 dollars instead of an integer of cent

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way to do this:

Given that your ranges are coming from DB, you will be using an array of something.  We could use a hash to represent values of each price range as shown below.

```
prices = [ {min: 0, max: 50, price: 1}, {min: 50, max: 100, price: 2} ]
weight = 50.5

prices.find {|i| (i[:min]...i[:max]).include? weight }[:price]
#=> 2
```

Also note the usage of `...` in range, which excludes the end value. Hence, `(0...50)` will not include `50`.  This will ensure that there is no overlap between ranges in case you had used `(0..50)`, `(50..100)`, or we don't skip a range of values if you had used `(0..50)` and `(51..100)`.