# Two versions of fibonacci, null expression

Tags: ruby

Here are two versions of fibonacci I thought of

```
def fibonacci( n )
  return  n  if ( 0..1 ).include? n
  ( fibonacci( n - 1 ) + fibonacci( n - 2 ) )
end
puts fibonacci( 5 )


def fib(n)
  if n == (0..1)
    return n
  elsif 
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
  end
end
puts fib(5)
```

Why doesent the second fib(n) work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `n == (0..1)` is never satisfied if `n` is a number. The range `0..1` is not a number. A minimum fix is:

```
(0..1) === n
```

Comment: I will delete my answer if it is offending as much as your comment is.

Comment: No, I am genuinely confused. No need to take offence

Comment: @cresjoy this case `===` is like `include?`, check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4467823/1301840)

Comment: I get a void value expression error on  return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2), I will check out that link though thanks

Comment: Now it tells me the stack level is too deep, I think im in unstoppable recursion

Comment: any thoughts? @sawa

Comment: His problem is that the direction of the `===` was wrong.

Comment: @danielrsmith Not only that. The OP hasn't used any.

Comment: @sawa I get that, my hunch is that the OP simple switched the `==` with `===` rather than having it be the exact way your answer was posted.  Since `===` is a method on the first operand you have to put the range first, or it doesn't know how to do the operation properly (using the numeric version). Upvoted since this is correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `elsif` in favor of `else` (since you have no case), and also reverse the `===`

```
def fib(n)
  if (0..1) === n
    return n
  else
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
  end
end
puts fib(5)
```

Comment: There is no "the" `===`.

Comment: Why does === need to be the other way around? Why does double equal not work?

Comment: `a === b` is just syntactic sugar for `a.===(b)`.  So the object `a` is having the `===` method run.  A number's `===` method is an equality comparison.  On the other hand `(0..1)` is a `Range` object, and it's `===` method is a "include" type operation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D .  `==` won't work because as the documentations states, it needs to be the exact same range.

Comment: @cresjoy you should accept sawa's answer it was correct.

Comment: May I ask why, when I did n == (0..1), it gave me a stack overflow error? I know this is syntatically wrong. But that error gives the impression of infinite recursion.

Comment: Since `n == (0..1)` never evaluated to true, you had no condition to stop the recursion.