# So I want the answer for the user just to include numbers from 0 to 9.. How do I do this?

Tags: ruby

So as I ask for in the title. How do I make a loop that breaks when the user has entered some values that contain only number, and if not it will say try again.

```
prompt = "> "
    puts "What is the salary for the accountant: "
    print prompt 
    while accountant = gets.chomp

      if accountant == (0..9)
        puts "Nice"

        break

      else 
        "try again"
        print prompt
      end 
    end 

      end
```

Comment: Right now you are comparing a `String` ( `accountant = gets.chomp`) to a `Range` (`(0..9)`) which will never be equivalent. What you want is to see if a number is in the range so `(0..9).cover?(accountant.to_i)` should work for you

Comment: `if accountant =~ /\A\d+\z/`

Comment: Also note that invalid answers will convert to zero - e.g. `"a".to_i == 0`. So a regex may be a better approach, as suggested above.

Comment: I found it out, used this 

 if accountant =~ /^-?[0-9]+$/

Comment: So a negative salary is permitted. Poor employees :D Anyway, I'd move to `/\A-?[0-9]+\z/` or something with a newline and something that is not a number would match. what @mudasobwa did suggest is good

Comment: You could use this `if (0..9).map(&:to_s).include?(accountant)`

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution with no regex would be:

```
accountant.chars.all?{|n| ("0".."9") === n}
```

You may want to read about the "===" operator in Ruby if you don't how it works yet as it may be confusing if you come from PHP or Javascript.
[What does the "===" operator do in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467538/what-does-the-operator-do-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line:

```
if accountant == (0..9)
```

This is checking whether the value is *equal* to a *range* - which is not what you wanted.

Since the input from `gets.chomp` will always be a *string*, you need to check whether it only contains the characters: `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"`, ... and `"9"`.

One way to do this is with a regular expression:

```
if accountant =~ /\A\d+\z/
```

- `\A` means "start of string"
- `\z` means "end of string"
- `\d+` means "one or more digit" (0-9)

---

Note that the solution you suggested in the comments, `/^-?[0-9]+$/`, is flawed since:

- `^` means "start of *line*" (so it would be possible to insert arbitrary other characters *before a newline*)
- `$` means "end of *line*" (so it would be possible to insert arbitrary other characters *after a newline*)
- `-?` also allows an optional hyphen character. Which is presumably *not* what you want in this context, since the input is a *salary* - which surely cannot be negative!