# Opsworks deployment doesn't have node[:deploy]

Tags: docker, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

My opsworks deployment's node doesnt have [:deploy] object
This is my Chef script

```
if node[:deploy] === nil

    Chef::Log.info("No deployment..")
    node[:deploy].each do |app, deploy|
        Chef::Log.info("deploy -#{ app }-")
    end
elsif
    # never goes here
end
```

i got this error on line 4

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly, i will advise you to read [What does the “===” operator do in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4467823/1184717).

i have a feeling that you meant to use `==`, rather than `===`. change your triple equal operator to double equal operator and give it a try...

you can use [`#nil?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/NilClass.html#method-i-nil-3F) if you want to make it more readable (depending on your ruby version). change

```
if node[:deploy] === nil
```

to

```
node[:deploy].nil?
```