# Ruby Case Statement: Return which player won — Rock, Paper, Scissors

Tags: ruby

Working on a Codewar challenge: **Rock, Paper,Scissors**. The aim is to return which player won! In case of a draw return Draw!.

**For example:**

```
rps('scissors','paper') // Player 1 won!
rps('scissors','rock') // Player 2 won!
rps('paper','paper') // Draw!
```

**my code:**

```
def rps(p1, p2)

case p1...p2

when  (p1 == 'rock' && p2 == 'scissors') ||
      (p1 == 'scissors' && p2 == 'paper') ||
      (p1 == 'paper' && p2 == 'rock')
  return "Player 1 won!"
  
when  (p1 == 'scissors' && p2 == 'rock') ||
      (p1 == 'paper' && p2 == 'scissors') ||
      (p1 == 'rock' && p2 == 'paper')
else (p1 == p2)
  return "Draw!"
end
end
```

**outcome:**

```
 player 1 win
Expected: "Player 1 won!", instead got: "Draw!"
Expected: "Player 1 won!", instead got: "Draw!"
Expected: "Player 1 won!", instead got: "Draw!"
 player 2 win
Expected: "Player 2 won!", instead got: "Draw!"
Expected: "Player 2 won!", instead got: "Draw!"
Expected: "Player 2 won!", instead got: "Draw!"
 draw
Test Passed: Value == "Draw!"
Test Passed: Value == "Draw!"
Test Passed: Value == "Draw!"
```

What do I need to change in my code for it to return "Player 1 Won!" and "Player 2 Won!"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `case` expression in Ruby works like this (see section 11.5.2.2.4 *The `case` expression* of the [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html) for details):

```rb
case object_of_interest
when category1
  some_expression
when category2
  some_other_expression
when category3
  another_expression
else
  an_entirely_different_expression
end
```

is (roughly) equivalent to

```rb
temp = object_of_interest

if category1 === temp
  some_expression
elsif category2 === temp
  some_other_expression
elsif category3 === temp
  another_expression
else
  an_entirely_different_expression
end
```

The `===` operator (I call it the [*case subsumption operator*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4467823/2988), but that is something I made up, not an official term) checks whether the right-hand operand can be subsumed under the receiver. What do I mean by that? Imagine, you had a drawer labelled with the receiver, would it make sense to put the right-hand operand into it?

So, if you have

```rb
foo === bar
```

this asks "if I have a drawer labelled `foo`, would it make sense to put `bar` into it?", or "if I interpret `foo` as describing a set, would `bar` be a member of that set?"

The default implementation of [`Object#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) is more or less just simple equality, it looks a bit like this (see also section 15.3.1.3.2 *`Kernel#===`* of the ISO/IEC 30170:2012 Ruby Language Specification):

```rb
class Object
  def ===(other)
    equals?(other) || self == other
  end
end
```

This is not exactly helpful, because it does not show what I mean by *case subsumption*. For that, we have to look at some of the overrides. For example, [`Module#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) (see also section 15.2.2.4.5 *`Module#===`* of the ISO/IEC 30170:2012 Ruby Language Specification):

> ## `mod === obj` → `true` or `false`
>
> *Case Equality*—Returns `true` if *obj* is an instance of *mod* or an instance of one of *mod*'s descendants. Of limited use for modules, but can be used in case statements to classify objects by class.

So, it is equivalent to

```rb
class Module
  def ===(other)
    other.kind_of?(self)
  end
end
```

So, it implements the question "If I had a drawer named `mod`, would it make sense to put `other` in it" as "Is `other` an instance of `mod`", and we can see that it makes sense:

```rb
Integer === 3       #=> true
Integer === 'Hello' #=> false

String  === 3       #=> false
String  === 'Hello' #=> true
```

If I have a drawer labelled `Integer`, does it make sense to put `3` in it? Yes, it does. What about `'Hello'`? No, it does not.

Another example is [`Range#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) (see also section 15.2.14.4.2 *`Range#===`* of the ISO/IEC 30170:2012 Ruby Language Specification):

> ## `rng === obj` → `true` or `false`
>
> Returns `true` if *obj* is between begin and end of range, `false` otherwise (same as `cover?`).

So, it implements the question "If I had a drawer named `rng`, would it make sense to put `other` in it" as "Does the range `rng` cover `other`", and we can see that it makes sense:

```rb
0..2 === 1 #=> true
0..2 === 3 #=> false
```

If I have a drawer labelled `0..2`, does it make sense to put `1` in it? Yes, it does. What about `3`? No, it does not.

The last example is [`Regexp#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) (see also section 15.2.15.7.4 *`Regexp#===`* of the ISO/IEC 30170:2012 Ruby Language Specification). Imagine a Regexp describing an infinite set of languages that match that Regexp:

```rb
/el+/ === 'Hello' #=> true
/el+/ === 'World' #=> false
```

If I have a drawer labelled `/el+/`, does it make sense to put `'Hello'` in it? Yes, it does. What about `'World'`? No, it does not.

So, your `case` expression:

```rb
case p1...p2
when p1 == 'rock' && p2 == 'scissors' || p1 == 'scissors' && p2 == 'paper' || p1 == 'paper' && p2 == 'rock'
  return 'Player 1 won!'
when p1 == 'scissors' && p2 == 'rock' || p1 == 'paper' && p2 == 'scissors' || p1 == 'rock' && p2 == 'paper'
else
  p1 == p2
  return 'Draw!'
end
```

Note that `else` doesn't have a conditional. It literally means "in every other case", so there is no need for a conditional. So, the `p1 == p2` is actually the first expression inside the `else` block. However, since it has no side-effects, and its value is completely ignored, it doesn't actually do anything at all.

Let's simplify that to:

```rb
case p1...p2
when something_that_is_either_true_or_false
  return 'Player 1 won!'
when something_that_is_either_true_or_false
else
  return 'Draw!'
end
```

This is equivalent to

```rb
temp = p1...p2
if    something_that_is_either_true_or_false === temp
  return 'Player 1 won!'
elsif something_that_is_either_true_or_false === temp
else
  return 'Draw!'
end
```

Now, depending on how exactly you call the `rps` method, those conditional expressions may be either `true` or `false`, but we don't know exactly which. What we *do* know, however, is that neither [`TrueClass#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/TrueClass.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) nor [`FalseClass#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/FalseClass.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) override `Object#===`, so they still have the same semantics: they simply test for equality. So, this is actually equivalent to

```rb
if    something_that_is_either_true_or_false == p1...p2
  return 'Player 1 won!'
elsif something_that_is_either_true_or_false == p1...p2
else
  return 'Draw!'
end
```

Here's the thing: a boolean will never be equal to a range. They aren't even the same type! What you are effectively asking in your `case` expression is

"If I have a drawer labelled `true`, does it make sense to put `p1...p2` into it?" or "If I have a drawer labelled `false`, does it make sense to put `p1...p2` into it?" It doesn't matter which of the two situations you have, because the answer is "No" in both cases.

So, there is, in fact, *no possible way* in which *any* of the `when` clauses can *ever* be `true`. Therefore, your `case` expression will always evaluate the `else` clause, or put another way, your entire method is completely equivalent to

```rb
def rps(_, _) # ignore all arguments
  'Draw!'
end
```

There is a second form of the `case` expression: when you leave out the `object_of_interest`, then it becomes equivalent to a series of conditionals, like this:

```rb
case
when conditional1
  some_expression
when conditional2
  some_other_expression
when conditional3
  another_expression
else
  an_entirely_different_expression
end
```

is (roughly) equivalent to

```rb
if conditional1
  some_expression
elsif conditional2
  some_other_expression
elsif conditional3
  another_expression
else
  an_entirely_different_expression
end
```

So, one way to fix your method, is to simply delete the `p1...p2`:

```rb
case # that is all we need to change to make it work
when p1 == 'rock' && p2 == 'scissors' || p1 == 'scissors' && p2 == 'paper' || p1 == 'paper' && p2 == 'rock'
  return 'Player 1 won!'
when p1 == 'scissors' && p2 == 'rock' || p1 == 'paper' && p2 == 'scissors' || p1 == 'rock' && p2 == 'paper'
else
  p1 == p2
  return 'Draw!'
end
```

That is literally all we need to change to make it work. Just delete that single expression. We can simplify it a bit further: first, as discussed above, we can remove the `p1 == p2`, because it doesn't do anything. Secondly, the `case` expression is an expression. It is not a statement. (In fact, there are no statements in Ruby. Everything is an expression.)

Ergo, the `case` expression evaluates to a value, in particular, it evaluates to the value of the branch that was taken. So, whenever you see something like

```rb
case foo
when bar
  return baz
when qux
  return frobz
end
```

that is equivalent to

```rb
return case foo
when bar
  baz
when qux
  frobz
end
```

Also, the last expression evaluated in a method body (or block body, lambda body, class definition body, or module definition body) is the value of the whole method (block, lambda, class definition, module definition), so in your case, the `return` is redundant there, too.

Lastly, your second `when` has no body, so it isn't doing anything, which means we can just remove it.

Which means the entire method becomes

```rb
case
when p1 == 'rock' && p2 == 'scissors' || p1 == 'scissors' && p2 == 'paper' || p1 == 'paper' && p2 == 'rock'
  'Player 1 won!'
else
  'Draw!'
end
```

Since there is only one condition, it doesn't really make sense for it to be a `case` expression at all, so we make it a *conditional expression* instead:

```rb
if p1 == 'rock' && p2 == 'scissors' || p1 == 'scissors' && p2 == 'paper' || p1 == 'paper' && p2 == 'rock'
  'Player 1 won!'
else
  'Draw!'
end
```

An alternative way of solving this with a `case` expression would be to actually *use* the fact that, when not specifically overridden, `===` just means equality:

```rb
case [p1, p2]
when ['rock', 'scissors'], ['scissors', 'paper'], ['paper', 'rock']
  'Player 1 won!'
when ['scissors', 'rock'], ['paper', 'scissors'], ['rock', 'paper']
'Player 2 won!'
else
  'Draw!'
end
```

Comment: You're a legend mate! Just had a proper read through this and will definitely be bookmarking this for future!

Comment: BTW, as the answer is already very long, I left this out, but the *really correct* way to handle this would be to have objects representing rock, paper, and scissors, and implement a `beats?` method, or maybe implementing `<`, `<=`, `==`, `>`, `>=` operators.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the completed code, but I believe you'll get the idea

```
def game(player1, player2)
  hash_game = {
    'scissors' => {
      'rock' => 'loss',
      'paper' => 'win'
    },
    'rock' => {
      ...
    },
    'paper' => {
      ...
    }
  }
  result = hash_game[player1][player2]
  "Player 1 #{result}!"
end
```

Comment: @KobadaTech you should thank by upvote or by accepting the answer

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing that as follows.

```
WINNERS = { rock: :scissors, paper: :rock, scissors: :paper }
  #=> {:rock=>:scissors, :paper=>:rock, :scissors=>:paper

def rps(p1,p2)
  puts case
  when WINNERS[p1] == p2
    "Player 1 won!"
  when WINNERS[p2] == p1
    "Player 2 won!"
  else
    "Draw!"
  end
end
```

```
rps(:rock, :scissors)     -> Player 1 won!
rps(:rock, :paper)        -> Player 2 won!
rps(:rock, :rock)         -> Draw!

rps(:paper, :rock)        -> Player 1 won!
rps(:paper, :scissors)    -> Player 2 won!
rps(:paper, :paper)       -> Draw!

rps(:scissors, :paper)    -> Player 1 won!
rps(:scissors, :rock)     -> Player 2 won!
rps(:scissors, :scissors) -> Draw!
```

Comment: this is very clean and also quite similar to what I originally had in mind. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @megas said, I would personally create a static class variable for each game possibility like so

```
@@GAMES = {}.tap do |h|
    win, lose, draw = ["Player 1 Wins!", "Player 2 Wins!", "Draw!"]

    h["rock"] = { "rock" => draw, "paper" => lose, "scissors" => win }
    h["paper"] = { "rock" => win, "paper" => draw, "scissors" => lose }
    h["scissors"] = { "rock" => lose, "paper" => win, "scissors" => draw }
end
```

Note that tap just lets you run code and alter the object your "tapping" before returning the object itself. This would allow you to just do

```
def play_game(p1, p2)
    puts @@GAMES[p1][p2]
end
```

This method also has the added benefit of being easy to change the messages for each outcome, and even add more outcomes, in case you wanted to implement "Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock" or something.