# How to use record id in case statement Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not having success in this before_save callback in Rails.

```
    before_save :set_shot_time
    after_save :set_status

    def set_shot_time
      case :id
      when 1..24
        puts self.shot_time = "9:00 a.m."
      when 25..49
        puts self.shot_time = "9:15 a.m."
      when 50..74
        puts self.shot_time = "9:30 a.m."
      when 75..99
        puts self.shot_time = "9:45 a.m."
      when 100..124
      ...
     end
```

This does not generate the desired attribute in the shot_time row of my pg database. Is it my syntax? I don't get any errors, and the log shows nothing either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case statement is using the symbol `:id` instead of the method `id` and hence none of the conditions get matched. It uses the case equality operator (`===`) under the hood. For e.g. `(1..24) === :id` returns `false` since `:id` does not belong in the range. I would recommend reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4467823/3724716) answer to gain a better understanding of the `===` operator. And the
`set_shot_time` method should be run after the record is created in an `after_create` callback since `id` will be `nil` before the record is created.

You can remove the `puts` calls which I guess you added for debugging.

```
after_create :set_shot_time
```

```
def set_shot_time
  return if shot_time

  case id
  when 1..24
    self.shot_time = "9:00 a.m."
  when 25..49
    self.shot_time = "9:15 a.m."
  when 50..74
    self.shot_time = "9:30 a.m."
  when 75..99
    self.shot_time = "9:45 a.m."
  # ...
  end

  save!
end
```

Note that without the `save!` method call at the end, the record won't be updated.

I'm not sure if I understand the logic but you can also write it as

```
def set_shot_time
  return if shot_time

  self.shot_time = case id
    when 1..24
      "9:00 a.m."
    when 25..49
      "9:15 a.m."
    when 50..74
      "9:30 a.m."
    when 75..99
      "9:45 a.m."
    # ...
    end

  save!
end
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, but I can't get it to work. Our church is hosting a vaccination day and the medical team can handle 24 persons every 15 minutes. Thus, as folks sign up the first 24 will get 9 a..m., etc. Is there a better way to do this? I appreciate your help!

Comment: @TomConnolly Just updated my answer. See if it helps.

Comment: Still nil. I'm bummed & will have to sleep on it. Thanks. I thought I was clever!

Comment: Wow. Adding stop! caused an error: stack level too deep

Comment: @Tom Connolly Looks like you're using `after_save`. You should use `after_create` instead.

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much!