# Comparing a rand to a range of numbers?

Tags: ruby

Is there a function in Ruby that'll allow me to do what I'm attempting here?

```
rand1 = rand(10)

puts rand1
puts ""

if rand1 == (0..9)
  print "yes"
else
  print "no"
end
```

This prints out no, how could line 6 be altered so that this will print out yes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining if a variable is within range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870507/determining-if-a-variable-is-within-range)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what, *exactly* is unclear to you about the documentation of `Range`. That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that future developers don't stumble across the same problems you did. Help make the world a better place!

Comment: @seasonalz : You are testing whether an object of class `Integer` is **equal** to an object of class `Range`.Of course you get false. An apple is not a pear. What do you want to achieve here?

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [`case` expression](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case%20Expression):

```
case rand
when 0..9
  print 'yes'
else 
  print 'no'
end
```

It also allows you to provide multiple ranges or numbers to compare against. Here's a contrived example:

```
case rand
when 0..2, 3, 4..9
  print 'yes'
else 
  print 'no'
end
```

Under the hood, `case` uses `===` to compare the given objects, i.e. the above is (almost) equivalent to:

```
if 0..2 === rand || 3 === rand || 4..9 === rand
  print 'yes'
else
  print 'no'
end
```

(note that the `when` objects become the receiver and `rand` becomes the argument)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Range#cover?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) which works like [`===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) in this case.

```
irb(main):001:0> (0..9).cover?(0.1)
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, use ===

```
rand1 = rand(10)

puts rand1
puts ""

if (0..9) === rand1
  print "yes"
else
  print "no"
end
```

Note: `rand1===(0..9)` won't work

And also you can use `member?`

```
rand1 = rand(10)

puts rand1
puts ""

if (0..9).member?(rand1)
  print "yes"
else
  print "no"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best option but yet an option (not covered here: [Determining if a variable is within range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870507/determining-if-a-variable-is-within-range))

```
rand1 >= (0..9).begin && rand1 <= (0..9).end
```

See Range docs, anyway: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Range.html#method-i-end